# Generate crystal report from dynamic stored procedure

Tags: crystal-reports

I have to create crystals report from stored procedure. But my column name from stored procedure are not fixed means my stored procedure is dynamic it column name change  every time. It problem to generate the crystals report because i do not mapped column name in stored procedure to crystals report. What I have to Do? Can it possible to generate dynamic crystals report ????

Comment: Dynamic column names and crystal reports will never work.

Comment: Any other solution for that??

Comment: Yes, don't use dynamic column names.

Comment: Do you need to export the data to Excel or preview it on screen ? Crystal is not the right tool to run a stored procedure with dynamic output but there are other options.